# How to load different views on the launch of the app based on existing user or returning user, iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

If I load the app for the first time it goes to the correct survey view, but then when i shut down the app by double clicking the home button and exiting out of it on the bottom of the iphone, then reopen the app, the app crashes instead of properly going to the returning user view controller, this view controller is just named viewController and the survey one is surveyViewController...

the following code does not work:

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;
@class SurveyViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SurveyViewController *home;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *home2;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SurveyViewController *viewController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SurveyViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
@synthesize viewController2 = _viewController2;
@synthesize home, home2, navController, navController2;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasFilledSurvey"] == NO) {

        home = [[SurveyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SurveyViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:home];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasFilledSurvey"];

    }
    else {

        home2 = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:home2];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navController2;

    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain a little further ? So far all I can guess is that there's something wrong in your ViewController class. What's the error message you get ?

Comment: The app just crashes and closes itself, no error report at all. My viewController class works if i just try to load that view as the home screen and leave out the surveyviewcontroller.  If there is anything else that would help you answer this let me know.

Comment: OT:  don't forget to synchronize your NSUserDefaults:   `    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

Comment: rayfleck- what will that synchronize do for nsuserdefaults?

Comment: If you're running this in debug you should see a crash or an exception being thrown in the log. You could add the exception breakpoint for more info: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html

Comment: Synchronize STORES what you have setup/changed.
Without it there will not be anything to load (could this be your crash?)